# How to fix my printWriter and get a full output on text file

Tags: java

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;

    public class Hw6Problem004 {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            {



                double j = 120;
                for (double i = 40; i >= 31; i--) {

                    //Create File object for the file 
                    File outFile = new File("temperature_table.text");

                    //Create the PrintWriter object
                    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(outFile);

                    pw.println("celsius  \tFahrenheit \t|       Fahrenheit \tCelsius");
                    double cTf = (double) Math.round(celsiusToFahrenheit(i) * 100) / 100;
                    double decimal = (double) Math
                            .round(fahrenheitToCelsius(j) * 100) / 100;
                    pw.println(i + "\t\t" + cTf + "\t\t|" + "\t" + j + "\t" + "\t"
                            + decimal);
                    System.out.println("");
                    j -= 10;

                    pw.close();
                }

            }

        }

        // • Converts a Celsius value to Fahrenheit
        public static double celsiusToFahrenheit(double celsius) {

            return (9.0 / 5) * celsius + 32;

        }

        // Converts a Fahrenheit value to Celsius
        public static double fahrenheitToCelsius(double fahrenheit) {

            return (5.0 / 9) * (fahrenheit - 32);

        }
    }
```

This is what I am getting:

```
 //       celsius   Fahrenheit  |       Fahrenheit  Celsius
 //       31.0      87.8        |   30.0        -1.11
```

I need to get this:

```
 //  celsius      Fahrenheit    | Fahrenheit     Celsius
 //   40.0      104.0       |   120.0       48.89
 //   39.0      102.2       |   110.0       43.33
 //   38.0      100.4       |   100.0       37.78
 //   37.0      98.6        |   90.0        32.22
 //   36.0      96.8        |   80.0        26.67
 //   35.0      95.0        |   70.0        21.11
 //   34.0      93.2        |   60.0        15.56
 //   33.0      91.4        |   50.0        10.0
 //   32.0      89.6        |   40.0        4.44
 //   31.0      87.8        |   30.0        -1.11
```

I am getting only the last row of my table on the text file.
 I need to show the whole output on my text file.

Comment: You create a new `File` for each row. You should put that outside the loop and only create the file once. Otherwise you just keep overwriting the file with the current loop iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should open and close the PrintWriter outside the loop :

```
            File outFile = new File("temperature_table.text");
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(outFile);
            for (double i = 40; i >= 31; i--) {                   

                pw.println("celsius  \tFahrenheit \t|       Fahrenheit \tCelsius");
                double cTf = (double) Math.round(celsiusToFahrenheit(i) * 100) / 100;
                double decimal = (double) Math
                        .round(fahrenheitToCelsius(j) * 100) / 100;
                pw.println(i + "\t\t" + cTf + "\t\t|" + "\t" + j + "\t" + "\t"
                        + decimal);
                System.out.println("");
                j -= 10;
            }
            pw.close();
```

Currently, in each iteration of the loop you are overwriting the output file.

Comment: When I do that it says that pw.close(); cannot be resolved @Efran

Comment: @user3269660 My mistake. The PrintWriter creation should also be outside the loop. See my edit.

Comment: Oh I see :)    I got it